# req.user is undefined in Sean.js

Tags: node.js, authentication, serialization, passport.js, sequelize.js

I'm working on a project using [Sean.js](https://github.com/seanjs-stack/seanjs) and recently I tried to add a middleware to secure my api routes. I followed the "article" example using the server.policy.js and when I try to use the req.user variable it says that is undefined. I started to investigate the problem and it comes that is something to do with passport.js. I have no more than 2 months working on this and I'm not very familiar with all of this.

On the `user.server.config.js` is where Serelize and Deserialize the sessions:

```
module.exports = function(app, db) {

  // Serialize sessions
  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    var userData = {
      id: user.id,
      firstName: user.firstName,
      lastName: user.lastName,
      displayName: user.displayName,
      username: user.username,
      email: user.email,
      profileImageURL: user.profileImageURL,
      roles: user.roles,
      additionalProvidersData: user.additionalProvidersData
    };
    done(null, userData);
  });

  // Deserialize sessions
  passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
  });

  // Initialize strategies
  config.utils.getGlobbedPaths(path.join(__dirname, './strategies/**/*.js')).forEach(function(strategy) {
    require(path.resolve(strategy))(config);
  });

  // Add passport's middleware
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
};
```

Is here the problem or should modify something else?. I believe that has something to with this because it also I have the problem that when I reload the session ends and I have to log in again.

Comment: SEAN.JS uses Redis to store sessions. Did you install and ran Redis?

Comment: Yeah I figure out later that I have to run Redis on the background, such a noob situation. But on the good part, I learned a lot on how works passport.js and session on node.js

Answer (score 0):

Like the commnet above. Sean.js use [Redis](https://redis.io/) to store sessions, So you need to intall it first and then run it and the session will be available on req.user